# Finding the value for the reproduction rate that will cause population stabilization

Tags: matrices

So essentially I have a matrix equation AB

A is a 4x4 matrix containing reproduction rate, survival rate and maturity rate. B is a 4x1 matrix containing the populations for each age group. How would I find the value for r subscript 2, that would eventually cause my population to stabilize?

```
A = 0      0.0043  ?       0
    0.9775 0.9111  0       0
    0      0.0736  0.9534  0
    0      0       0.0452  0.9804

B = 4
    18
    15
    23
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the equation?  Do you mean $x_{n+1} = A x_n$ with $x_0 = B$, and you want to find $A_{12}$?

If so, you want $1$ to be an eigenvalue, so $\det(A-I) = 0$, and this is true for
$A_{12} = 0.0303572987323474$ approximately.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry, I haven't yet actually delved into eigenvalues, so unfortunately I'm not sure what that means, however, yes the equation is asking me to find the equilibrium, So X subscript n+1 = X subscript n with X subscript 0 = B